# Wordpress page redirect to home

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

My page is redirecting to home due to some problem in code.

I have three links:

1. Intraday Tips (https://www.xyz.in/intraday)
2. Positional Tips (https://www.xyz.in/positional)
3. Commodity Tips (https://www.xyz.in/commodity)

The first link is working fine while other two links are redirecting to home

Initially it was fine as there was a term and condition page after the link as in code below.

```js
<?php  if(isset($_POST['accepted']) && $_POST['agree'] == 1) {
   while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
 <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
 <?php the_content(); ?>
 <?php endwhile; ?>
 <?php } else {  ?>
 
  
 <?php 
 query_posts('page_id=182'); 
   while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
 <h2>Terms & Conditions</h1>
 <?php the_content(); ?>
 <form method="post" action="">
 <p><input type="checkbox" value="1" id="agree" name="agree" style="margin-right: 10px;" /><label for="agree">I accept terms and conditions.</label><input type="submit" id="accepted" name="accepted" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" value="View Tips" title="Check the box to proceed" style="margin-left:10px;"/></p>
 </form>
 <?php endwhile; ?>
  <?php } ?>
```

Now I have modified code to bypass intermediate page "Terms and condition" and problem started.

```js
   <?php  if(isset($_POST['accepted']) && $_POST['agree'] == 1) {
   while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
 <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
 <?php the_content(); ?>
 <?php endwhile; ?>
 <?php } else {  ?>
 
 
   <?php 
 while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
 <?php the_content(); ?>
 <?php endwhile; ?>
  <?php } ?>
```

But this only work for first link other links are redirecting to home page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry guys, I got the issue.....:-)

In header.php there was a code that was forcing it to redirect to home for certain condition.

```js
if(is_page(array(220,221)) && !is_user_logged_in()){
 wp_redirect(home_url());
 exit();
}
```

I simply removed it and the things are working fine.

Thanks a Lot